# Is this predicate-logic formula a tautology?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

$$F(x) \rightarrow \forall x F(x)$$
My teacher says that the formula is a tautology. Because when the antecedent is false, all the formula should always true, and when the antecedent is true, consequent can be infered by using $\forall +$ rule.

Is this correct? I thought some problem in it, but I can't point it out. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a well formed formula.

Comment: According the the usual semantics for predicate logic, the formula is **not** valid (i.e. true in every interpretation).

Comment: Is that means $F(x)$ equals to $\forall x F(x)$ ?

Comment: This is the issue: if the semantics adopted "equates" $Fx$ with $\forall x Fx$, then obviously the above formula is *valid*. But there is a different approach, where an interpretation assigns to a free variable a "specific" objcet. If so, the formula is not valid: $(n=0) \to \forall n (n=0)$

Comment: Bit, if so, do you mean that the above formula will be: $\forall x (Fx \to \forall x Fx)$? If so, it is not a tautology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The given open formula $$F(x) \rightarrow \forall x F(x)$$ contains
   a free variable $x,$ so it is merely a **propositional function**
   (predicate) rather than a proposition (sentence).
2. It is logically equivalently to $$F(x) \rightarrow \forall y F(y).$$
3. It is **invalid** (false in some interpretation),
   and therefore **not a tautology** (neither an FOL nor a PL tautology):
          domain
   of discourse: days of $2021$
          $F(x)$ := $\;x$
   is Friday
4. But it is **satisfiable** (true in some interpretation, i.e., not a contradiction):
          domain of discourse: $\mathbb Z$
     
       $F(x)$ := $\;x+1=x.$

Comment: Sound right, thank you.